Unity で iOS 向けにビルドすると plist で変更した箇所が初期化されてしまう
UnityにおいてiOSアプリを製作中です。アプリでは位置情報を取得したい。その際にinfo.plistに位置情報を取得する際にスマホに表示される情報を書き込みました。
しかし、iOSとしてビルドすると変更した部分が初期化（削除）されてしまいます。対処方法を教えてほしいです。

ビルド時に info.plist が生成されるので、上書きされているということではないですか？[Player Settings] - [Other Settings] -[Location Usage Description] への記載では、同様のことが実現できないですか？「https://qiita.com/isa130pull/items/cf4642b6df387eade337」にこのあたり記載があります。
